# All js functions need in .js file if I use the RequireJs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I want to use RequireJs in my project, but I found that I can't write the following code

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
       <input type="button"  />
       <script>
           // Use the jQuery
           $(function() {
              //some code
             }
           )
       </script>
       <input />
       <input />

       // I had added the jQuery in required shim and jQuery is working in RequireJs.
       <script data-main="scripts/main" src="/scripts/require.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

There was an error `$ is undefined`, when the page was loaded. 
I looked up a lot articles, but I can't solve it. How can I handle this? I don't want to move the sample js function to .js file.

Comment: include <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: otherwise include this <script data-main="scripts/main" src="/scripts/require.js"></script> in head section

Comment: If you are not going to use jQuery in the script tag in head, if you just want the on $(document).ready event listener. 
Then you could do `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { //some code })`
If you want to support < internet explorer 9 you can have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/

Comment: From Mr RequireJS himself: [_This project shows how jQuery can be used with RequireJS_](https://github.com/jrburke/require-jquery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first `$` means nothing in JavaScript but is used by the popular [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/). `JavaScript !== jQuery`.

Secondly assuming you have loaded jQuery via require.js you need to put your initial script tag after 
`<script data-main="scripts/main" src="/scripts/require.js"></script>` as it is being called before require.js.

Thirdly require.js asynchronously loads files so you must wrap your code in the `require()` or `define()` tag with a list of dependancies so it only calls them once they have been loaded.

e.g.

```
<html>
   <head>
       <script data-main="scripts/main" src="/scripts/require.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <input type="button"  />
       <script>
          /* 
             RequireJS is asynchronous so you must wrap your code
             in "require(["jQuery"], ...)" so it only calls it once
             jQuery has been loaded. Each included script is available 
             to you as a parameter in the callback function.
          */
          require(["jQuery"], function($) {
              $(function() {
              });
          });
       </script>
       <input />
       <input />
   </body>
</html>
```

Your settings should look like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'jQuery': 'path/to/jquery'
    },
    shim: {
        'jQuery': {
            exports: '$'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks your answer. But if the js code is minify, that is not good for me. I must include jQuery twice. `main.js` is one, in the page is two.

Comment: @user2306785 This isn't including it twice, and minification doesn't affect anything (it's still the same code). You include it in main.js and by using `require()` you tell your script to wait for it to load and ensure your code is scoped correctly to use it. You aren't loading it twice.

Comment: How can I tell the `require()` to find the `jQuery` code in the main.js, because all the .js files are combined to one file.

Comment: @user2306785 You can't and you have completely missed the point of require.js which is for modular code - your code isn't modular. You should keep your javascript separate during development and then combine them via the [require.js optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) when you want to publish them. If you don't know why you are using something then don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote in your question:

> All js functions need in .js file if I use the requirejs?

And with the definition of RequireJS:

> RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader.
>   Using a modular script loader like RequireJS will improve the speed and quality of your code.

So doing such inserting inline `<script>` tags in your page **is not a good idea**.

However, in answer to your question, because RequireJS load the scripts `asynchronously`, so you don't know when jQuery will load, and **you can not use inline scripts** as old schools, you need to use <del>`define` or</del> `require` methods as **`George Reith` wrote in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16622190/1823761)**.

Comment: I think `define` is not OK, you check here: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch

Answer (score 0):

You also have to include jQuery. There is a [whole manual page](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) devoted to this on requirejs.org which should help you out.

Maybe what you want is also explained [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html). Taken from there:

```
require(["helper/util"], function(util) {
    //This function is called when scripts/helper/util.js is loaded.
    //If util.js calls define(), then this function is not fired until
    //util's dependencies have loaded, and the util argument will hold
    //the module value for "helper/util".
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Require.js doesn't even implement $. Why are you even wrapping you function in $(..)?

Comment: Not only that but he calls `$()` before require.js is even loaded.

Comment: Sure, but without requiresjs implementing $ it doesn't matter

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain the detail of my questions, I want to use the jQuery in my sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your sample script tag after the requirejs script tag. Currently your sample function is executed before requirejs gets a chance to load jQuery.

Comment: I tried to move `<script data-main="scripts/main" src="/scripts/require.js"></script>` in the <head>, but it was not working.

Comment: I guess you need to wrap your sample function also in a `require(["jquery"], function($) { .. })` (or was it `define` I always get those mixed up) to let requirejs know you need jquery, otherwise it can decide not to load it.